# Does $p^n$ divide $\binom{p^{n+m-1}}{m}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

> Let $n, m \in \mathbf N$ and $p$ an odd prime number. Then does  $p^n$ divide $\binom{p^{n+m-1}}{m}$ ?

It seems true, but I can not find a clue. Can I have any hint?

Comment: `\quad` inside `\binom`? What the...

Comment: Since '-1' and ')' overlap, I inserted /quad.

Comment: Don't. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint
$$\binom{p^{n+m-1}}{m}=\dfrac{p^{n+m-1}}{m}\binom{p^{n+m-1}-1}{m-1}$$

Comment: You mean $\frac{p^{m+1}}{m} \binom{p^{n+m+1}-1}{m-1}$ is an integer. How do we know this?

Comment: It is clear, because $m\nmid p^{n+m-1}$ so  must have $m|\binom{p^{n+m-1}-1}{m-1}$

Comment: @math110 Not sure what you mean by $m \nmid p^{n+m-1}$.  What if $m=p$?

Comment: oh, if $m=p$, is also such $p^n|\binom{p^{n+m-1}}{m}$

Comment: I understand it and add my answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I post an answer following math110's hint.
To complete the proof, we have to show $\frac{p^{m-1}}{m} \binom{p^{n+m-1}-1}{m-1}$ is an integer.
Let $m = p^r a$ where $a$ does not have a factor $p$.
It suffices to show that $r \leq  m-1$.
If then, 
$$\frac{p^{m-1}}{m} \binom{p^{m-1}-1}{m-1}$$
$$= \frac{p^{m-1-r}}{a} \binom{p^{n+m-1}-1}{m-1}.$$
Since $a$ has no factor of $p$, $a$ must divide $\binom{p^{n+m-1}-1}{m-1}$.

> Lemma. If $p$ is an integer $\ge 2$, then $p^r \ge r+1$.
>
> proof. For $r=0$, it is obvious.
>   Using induction on $r$, for $r \ge 1$, 
>   $p^r = p p^{r-1} \ge 2r = r +r \ge r+1$.

By the lemma, $m = p^r a \ge (r+1)a \ge r+1$.

$\mathbf{QED}$

Comment: Small but important wording correction: We already have that $\frac{p^{n+m-1}}{m} \binom{p^{n+m-1}-1}{m-1}$ is an integer (since it's the same binomial coefficient as in the question).  What you're trying to show is that $\frac{p^{m-1}}{m} \binom{p^{n+m-1}-1}{m-1}$  is an integer.  Also, you can simplify your Lemma to just "$p^r \ge r+1$" which is all you end up using.

Comment: @ErickWong I correted my answer. Thank you.